# Need help in ignoring certain lines when reading a file so that I don't have to include them in the calculations using VScode

Tags: c++

Okay, so I am writing a program that reads a file and prints all the lines in it. I don't want it to print lines that start with @ and + and print all the other lines.

The code that I have written looks like this [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCZC5.png)

The output looks like the following [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tGNw.png). So I want the output to print only those lines without starting with + and @.
I have stuck with this problem for a while and will really appreciate it if anyone can provide any hints as to what to do?

Thanks in Advance

Sorry I couldn't format the right coding style on stack overflow because I'm new but if you need help in understanding it don't hesitate to ask me

Regards,

Abdul Hadi

Comment: don't post images of code or terminal output, copy/paste the text

Comment: remove all the `visual-studio` tags and add a tag for the used language, it has NOTHING to do with the used editor/IDE, and also not with coding style. But more with: who wants to write my assignment.

Comment: I don't understand it is a visual studio editor that I am using and I have written most of the code myself I am not asking for anyone to write my assignment. just asking for a little help. If you can help me where I should post it then please guide me. Also I don't understand why I'm not allowed to post images of code ? Sorry for my ignorance but I'm just trying to understand this platform

Comment: If I want to test your code or modify it a bit I first have to type it all from an image instead of copy/paste from the web page. Also it is not sure the image will survive the life time of SO. The image host site can be out any time and then your question is unusable. Showing an image of an error message does not make it possible to search for other users who have the same problem.

Comment: You have a C++ problem and the editor is irrelevant. And your code does not show any try of solving the problem yourself, so it can be classified as: can you do my homework. Your code looks like the "start" code supplied by a teacher.

Comment: Thank You so much for telling me. Yes, I see my mistake now also I am sorry to say that I did post the code that Sir gave me without any major additions to it. I have posted another question this time with code and I did put my own effort into it aswell. Hopefully someone can answer my question this time. Thanks again